# How to set a locale encoding for postgresql on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm using Windows 7. When I get an error making some query to postgresql database, I see �� ��������� instead of usual message.

The problem isn't original and I found many links on the web with solutions of the problem, but nothing helped me. I suppose I need to have lc_collate and lc_ctype in **ru_RU.UTF-8** encoding (look at screenshots below).

I have this in postgresql (encoding | lc_collate | lc_ctype)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnj0z.jpg)

And I have this on Windows

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC25X.jpg)

I found that I need to make a cluster using this settings:

```
initdb -U myuser -E UTF8 --locale=russian_russia -D path_to_new_cluster
```

But new cluster has the same lc_collate and lc_ctype: **Russian_Russia.1251**

How can I fix this?

Sorry for my English. Regards.

Comment: Please do not put links to externally hosted images: they can become unavailable later. Put them into your post as images or as text.

Comment: I believe that the problem is with the Windows font used rather than with the database.

Comment: @EugenePrimako Sorry I couldn't find how to do that while I was writing the question. So I just decided to use more simple way.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe But I see these encoding errors in a browser. I always thought a browser uses its own fonts rather anything else (in such cases)